# Creating sessions

Tags: php, session

I need help creating sessions in php. I need a session for login and then if the user wants to change their username they can but. I know how to change a username but it is different when using sessions. Can anyone provide me with some examples or information on creating sessions. More specifically sessions that I need.

Oh I almost forgot I am using mysql and php myadmin. I am aware of the new ways of doing things with mysqli but this is purely for learning purposes.

Comment: 1. Show code. 2. Have you read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)?

Comment: Did you both to Google this first? And if you’re aware that MySQL is deprecated and MySQLi is one of the new ways of writing PHP, why not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['username'] = 'Subie';

    $username = $_SESSION['username']
?>
```

Session are pretty easy I believe you always need the **session_start()** before any session related things can be done.

Once I set the **$_SESSION['username']** I can now call it in any php script the user might visit.

Here's a good overview on sessions... http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Is anything on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/) actually good?

Comment: For a basic overview of functions I believe so. As a tool for learning entire programming languages most likely not.

Answer (score 0):

OK

At the top of every page you need your session data to exist.

```
session_start();
```

if you set a $_SESSION variable like so

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

then you can just override it like so

```
 $_SESSION['foo'] = 'foo foo bar';
```

or unset it like this

```
unset($_SESSION['foo']);
```

and you can destroy a session like so

```
session_destroy();
```

[PHP Sessions Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php)

Please do some reading and type some experimental code this is very basic stuff.